# On constructing a histogram using matplotlib, on what occasions should one expect the following error: ValueError: `bins` must be 1d, when an array

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, histogram

I am receiving the error `` ValueError: `bins` must be 1d, when an array `` on construction of a histogram with matplotlib. I want to debug it myself, only wanting a direction, so I am not displaying the code.

Comment: It seems to me that the error is as understandable as it can be. `bins` has more dimensions than expected.

Answer (score -1):

As i understand your question you mast use not hyst

```
insert_axes.bar(x = tips_per_day['day'], height = tips_per_day['max'], 
                width = 0.6, align = 'edge')
insert_axes.bar(x = tips_per_day['day'], height = tips_per_day['min'], 
                width = -0.6, align = 'edge')
```